# Probabilities of choosing cards to complete a set

Tags: probability

A certain brand of tea has a picture card in every packet. The cards form a set of $50$ different pictures and are distributed among the packets so that any packet purchased is equally likely to contain any one of the cards.

A boy has collected $47$ different cards. What is the probability that he will get the $3$ cards he needs to complete the set if he opens at most four packets?

Comment: Read your book or search the web about the "coupon collector's problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can assume he opens all four packets in any case. Now we want to find the probability that the three missing cards are among those four. There are $50^4$ possible outcomes, which are all equally likely! How many of these contain the three cards?

- $4\cdot 47\cdot 6$ outcomes with four different cards. (the $4$ is the position of the other card, $47$ is the other card, $6$ is the number of permutations of the three cards)
- $3\cdot 6\cdot 2$ outcomes with one of the three cards twice. (we have one of $3$ cards twice, $\binom{4}{2}=6$, $2$ is the number of permutations of the other two cards)

So the probability that he completes his set is $\frac{1164}{50^4}=0.00018624$